# Indent text in ordered list

Tags: html, css

I want to show my text content like below picture. How to do?
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980379/custom-list-styles-for-ordered-lists) but it doesn't indent from the second line.
I also tried to put that content in < table > with 2 rows and 2 column but the problem is I can't margin < table > as I wish. < table > has many margin and padding problems.

[image]

Update:

The code indent correctly but the problem is I can't margin the table like I want.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>(1) </td> 
        <td>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>(2) </td> 
        <td>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bdpz/7/).

This is using a normal list and a [CSS counter](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp) to create the list numbers. It will reset with every `ol` to start from the beginning again.

Source: [StackOverflow: How can you customize the numbers in an ordered list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877/how-can-you-customize-the-numbers-in-an-ordered-list)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8Bdpz/) ?

```
<ol>
<li>content heerrrrrrrrrrrrere content heerrrrrrrrrrrrere content heerrrrrrrrrrrrere</li>
<li>content heerrrrrrrrrrrrere content heerrrrrrrrrrrrere content heerrrrrrrrrrrrere</li>
</ol>​
```

---

```
ol{padding-left:80px;list-style-type:decimal;}

li{
    width:100px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

​

Comment: No, it must be (1), (2), ... That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

***[Demo][1]***

HI now used to this counter reset in css3

As like this

**Css**

```
body {counter-reset:section;}
h1 {counter-reset:subsection;}
h1:before
{
counter-increment:section;
content:"Section " counter(section) ". ";
}
h2:before 
{
counter-increment:subsection;
content:counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>HTML tutorials</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>XHTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>

<h1>Scripting tutorials</h1>
<h2>JavaScript</h2>
<h2>VBScript</h2>

<h1>XML tutorials</h1>
<h2>XML</h2>
<h2>XSL</h2>
```

[***[Demo][2]***](http://tinkerbin.com/nY5vYBcG)

---

Updated ***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/mtOgW1fG)***

Comment: No, it must be (1), (2), .. and the second, third line indent a tab.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/4ffT9/)**

CSS

```
ul {
    counter-reset:myCounter;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}    
ul li {
    padding-left:30px; /* adjust it to your custom font needings */
    position:relative;
    counter-increment:myCounter;
}
ul li:before {
    content:"("counter(myCounter)") ";
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
}​
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>Content here<br>and here<br>and here</li>
<li>Some more content here<br>and here<br>and here</li>
</ul>​
```