# HTML List Text indentation after number

Tags: html, css

how can I increase the margin between the numeral and the text in an ordered list?

i.e.

```
<ol>
  <li>text 1</li>
  <li>text 2</li>
  <li>text 3</li>
</ol>
```

Produces

1. text 1
2. text 2
3. text 3

And I want

1. __ text 1
2. __ text 2
3. __ text 3

Where __ is an arbitrary indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635598/indent-text-in-ordered-list?rq=1)

I modified the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geZf5/) to work for what I needed.

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
li {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: counter(item) ".";
    counter-increment: item;
    width: 2em;
    margin-left: -2em;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to mark this as answered in case future visitors have a similar question.

Comment: Can't for two days because its mine.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ol>
<li><span class="indent">text 1</span></li>
<li><span class="indent">text 2</span></li>
<li><span class="indent">text 3</span></li>
</ol>
<style="text/css">
ol li .indent{padding-left:20px;}
</style>
```

Comment: That does not work. It indents the whole line, not the text after the number.

Comment: It works but it is an extremely long list and I dont want to overload it with so many tags, it shouldn't be necessary to add a tag to each text to achieve this

Comment: You're right. As @Marc pointed out in his jsfiddle example, it shouldn't be necessary. But it looks like you found the answer, so good on you.